# Code coverage report using Slather

Tags: swift, code-coverage, xcode7.3

I'm generating a code coverage report in Xcode 7.3 using Slather

```
slather coverage --show --scheme SchemaName --workspace WorkspaceName.xcworkspace ProjectName.xcodeproj
```

The problem is that, it generates the report for some of the Foundation class files as well. I want to generate report consisting only project files.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ignore those explicitly. Add `--ignore '../*'` to ignore everything outside of the root folder, for example. This will catch all of those.

Comment: how do i also ignore specific folder inside the root folder?

Comment: You may be able to use the --ignore option multiple times, or you could always switch to using the yaml file to configure it